# How to have the variable in a class updated when its value is set in another class?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm rather new with AS3, so forgive me if my question appears stupid.

Let me clarify what I want specifically: The Player goes on a mission, in which he would earn points when he catches some objects on his way, for example object A gives one point, object B gives two points, object C gives bonus points, etc... IF the Player hits some obstacle on his way, he fails the mission and he has to replay the game until he reaches the destination (end of level).

So what I want is that how I can store the points that the Player earned before he hits the obstacle and the earned points would be accumulated every time the Player has to replay the game until he reaches the end of the game level so that the total points the Player earned would be the sum of all the points, including those that he earned before he actually reaches the end of the game level.

My Class Player is the subclass of the class Box that belongs to the framework WCK. Is there a way for me to implement Dependency Injection properly to pass the variables to the other class in order to store them there?

Thank you in advance for your help!

ADDED: Here is what I implemented based on Amy's example with some adjustment to suit the setup of my game. It still doesn't work as the value of variable _totalEarnedPoints did not update the variable _earnedPoints in Class PlayerClient via EventDispatcher when I tried to retrieve it back in Class Player for accumulating all the points. I'm not sure what I did wrong or missed anything else? Can anyone please point out and tell me how to retrieve back the variable _totalEarnedPoints from Class PlayerClient?

CLASS Player:

```
package  
{

public class Player extends Box  
{  
    private var contacts:ContactList;  
    private var myLoader:SWFLoader;  
    private var mcTemp:MovieClip;  
    private var bonusPoints:int = 0;  
    private var onePoint:int = 0;  
    private var twoPoints:int = 0;  
    private var objectACount:int = 0;  
    private var objectBCount:int = 0;  
    private var objectCCount:int = 0;  
    private var replayCount:int = 0;
    protected var _earnedPoints:int; 
    private var myPlayerClient:PlayerClient = new PlayerClient();  
}

public function Player()  
{  
    super();  
}

public override function create():void  
{  
    super.create();  
    listenWhileVisible(this, ContactEvent.BEGIN_CONTACT, handleContact);  
    contacts = new ContactList();  
    contacts.listenTo(this);  
}

public function handleContact(e:ContactEvent):void   
{  
    //Detect collison with other static objects  
    var myObjectA:objectA = e.other.m_userData as objectA;  
    var myObjectB:objectB = e.other.m_userData as objectB;  
    var myObjectC:objectC = e.other.m_userData as objectC;  
    var myObstacle:obstacle = e.other.m_userData as obstacle;       

    if(myObjectC)   
    {
        objectCCount++;  
        myObjectC.remove();  
        if (objectCCount > 0)  
        {  
           bonusPoints = bonusPoints + 5;                   
        }               
    }

    else if(myObjectA) 
    {
        objectACount++;
        myObjectA.remove();
        if (objectACount > 0)
        {
           onePoint = onePoint + 1;                         
        }
    }

    else if(myObjectB) 
    {
        objectBCount++;
        myObjectB.remove();
        if (objectBCount > 0)
        {
          twoPoints = twoPoints + 2;                            
        }
    }       
    else if(myObstacle)
        {               
        var myEarnedPoints:int = myPlayerClient.totalEarnedPoints;
        _earnedPoints = bonusPoints + onePoint + twoPoints + myEarnedPoints;
        dispatchEvent(new Event("EarnedPointChanged"));

        myLoader = new SWFLoader("myMovie.swf",{container:swfHolder,alpha:0,onComplete:completeHandler});
       //adds the loader content to the display list before raw content is loaded.
       addChild(myLoader.content);
       stop();
       myLoader.load();

       function completeHandler(e:LoaderEvent):void
       {
          replayCount++;

          if (replayCount <= 1)
          {
                TweenMax.to(e.target.content, 1, {alpha:1});
                mcTemp = myLoader.rawContent;
                mcTemp.gotoAndPlay(1);
          }
          else if (replayCount >= 1)
          {
                mcTemp = myLoader.rawContent.stop();
                myLoader.unload();
                mcTemp = null;  
          }

       }
       myObstacle.remove();

     }              

}

public function get earnedPoints():int  
{  
     return _earnedPoints;  
}  
}
```

CLASS PlayerClient

```
package  
{

public dynamic class PlayerClient extends MovieClip
{
    private var _totalEarnedPoints:int;
    protected var _player:Player;

    public function get player():Player
    {
        return _player;
    }

    public function set player(value:Player):void 
    {
        if (value != _player) 
        {
            if (_player) 
            {
                //[prevent memory leaks][2]
                _player.removeEventListener("EarnedPointChanged", updatePlayerScore);
                //don't need this if we don't have a player
                removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, cleanUp);
            }
            _player = value;
            if (_player) 
            {
                //listen for changes
                _player.addEventListener("EarnedPointChanged", updatePlayerScore);
                //we added a listener to the new player, need to make sure is removed
                addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, cleanUp);
            }
        }
    }

    protected function cleanUp(e:Event):void 
    {
        _player.removeEventListener("EarnedPointChanged", updatePlayerScore);
    }


    protected function updatePlayerScore(e:Event):void 
    {
        _totalEarnedPoints = _player.earnedPoints;

    }


    public function get totalEarnedPoints():int
    {
        return _totalEarnedPoints;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my question resolved by myself: I used SharedObject method to store the points and then retrieve the point value back into my class Player for accumulation. EventDispatcher did pass the points to the other class, but all the points value get back to initial state once Player hits the obstacle and the game replays, which makes it difficult to retrieve the points I passed to the other class back to the class Player for accumulation. SharedObject method did help me resolve this problem for my case study.

Answer (score 1):

First, what you're doing is going to cause you a world of hurt unless your project is a banner or something that you know 100% that you will work on for 2 days and never look at again. See http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-brittle-global-state-singletons/

What you need to realize is that your Points.pointsEarned looks like it will only ever change if you create a new instance of Player, and if you have several players, each new Player will have a higher number of points to start out with than the one before. That's probably not what you want. You don't really say what it is that you want, so let me throw out one thing that you *could* want and tell you how to code it. If that's not right, we'll go from there.

## Edit:

OK, so now we know that you want to be able to just increment the earned points, so this Class now becomes much simpler (check the revision history of the post to see what parts were removed):

```
package{
  public class Player extends EventDispatcher {
    protected var _earnedPoints:int;
    public function Player() {
       super();//not passing a parameter, so target of events will be this
    }
    public function get earnedPoints():int {
       return _earnedPoints;
    }
    public function set earnedPoints(value:int):void {
       if (value != _earnedPoints) {
          _earnedPoints = value;
          //other Classes can listen for this to see if earnedPoints has changed:
          dispatchEvent(new Event('earnedPointsChanged');
       }
    }
  }
}
```

You didn't ask about this part, but I think it's a necessary part for you to understand. I'm going to explain it just in case it's not obvious. Your "objects" need to have a Class of their own:

```
package {
   class TargetObject extends MovieClip {
      public var points:int;
   }
}
```

You can set those values when each TargetObject is created, or you can create several subclasses, where the value is hard-coded.

So now, whenever there's a collision, you can do something like this:

```
_player.earnedPoints += target.points;
```

When you set that variable, your PlayerClient will update, even when it is set from another Class.

In summary, you need to generate an event that other instances can listen for to update themselves:

```
package {
   public class PlayerClient extends MovieClip {
      public var playerScoreText:TextField;//assume this is on stage
      protected var _player:Player;
      //assume [dependency injection][1] 
      public function get player():Player {
         return _player;
      }
      public function set player(value:Player):void {
         if (value != _player) {
            if (_player) {
               //[prevent memory leaks][2]
               _player.removeEventListener('earnedPointsChanged', updatePlayerScore);
               //don't need this if we don't have a player
               removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, cleanUp);
            }
            _player = value;
            if (_player) {
               //listen for changes
               _player.addEventListener('earnedPointsChanged', updatePlayerScore);
               //we added a listener to the new player, need to make sure is removed
               addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, cleanUp);
            }
         }
      }
      protected function cleanUp(e:Event):void {
          _player.removeEventListener('earnedPointsChanged', updatePlayerScore);
      }
      /* This will trigger no matter what changes the value of
         earnedPoints or bonusPoints.
      */
      protected function updatePlayerScore(e:Event):void {
          if (playerScoreText) /*in case it wasn't put on stage */ {
              playerScoreText.text = _player.earnedPoints
          }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: I knew there is something wrong with my code as I'm new with AS3, so please bear with me...  I have question regarding your code that I don't know if I can apply in my case: Since I built my game based on the framework of [WCK](http://www.sideroller.com/wck/), the class Player is the subclass of the class Box, which is how it was built in the framework WCK. I don't really know how to make the class Player to be also the subclass of EventDispatcher like you did in your code in order to dispatch events. Can I import flash.Event.* instead to implement your code?  Much appreciated!

Comment: I revised my question above so you can see clearly what I want.  I do want to implement Dependency Injection like you did to get things worked properly in a clean way. So I really appreciate your helping me to get this resolved.

Comment: If you walk the tree of dependency, Box is ultimately a subclass of MovieClip, which is an EventDispatcher.

Comment: I added my code to my question above for implementing your example, but it seems that it does not work in my case. Can you please take a look and tell me what I did wrong? Thanks.